# Wrong banner on migrated answer

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, migrated-questions, migration-notice

[This deleted answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/671049/44126) is decorated with a banner which says it has been converted to a comment:

[image: Deleted answer banner]

That is not what happened. The question was migrated to another site, and the answer was migrated away with it. The banner is wrong.

(In a confusing but probably irrelevant coincidence, that particular answer was originally posted as a series of comments, and converted to an answer by its author at the suggestion of another user.)